# Weka packages and extends

Tags: java, classification, weka

I have this line of code:

```
public class Id3 extends DistributionClassifier {
```

but I am getting the error: cannot find class Distribution Classifier

and I have the Weka package and also added :

```
import weka.core.*;
```

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: you probably have to import `weka.classifiers.DistributionClassifier`. See http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~ablumer/weka/doc/weka.classifiers.DistributionClassifier.html

Comment: I am getting cannot find symbol - class DistributionClassifier now :(

Comment: What version of Weka are you using? They changed the API massively between the current stable and dev version.

Comment: I found a way to avoid Weka now because I couldn't manage. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~ablumer/weka/doc/weka.classifiers.DistributionClassifier.html

```
import weka.classifiers.DistributionClassifier;
```